# List of data file formats supported in QGIS including read/write support

Tags: qgis, editing, file-formats

Is there a list of data file formats supported in QGIS, including information about read/write support? What I'm looking for is something like:

- Geopackage: r/w
- Esri Shapefile: r/w
- CSV: r
- KML: r
- etc.

The documentation has a section "[Exploring Data Formats and Fields](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html?highlight=file%20formats#vector-data)".

However, there is no simple overview over read/write support and you have to read through a lot of text that does not always mention explicitly which of the formats are editable.

In fact, the vector layer export dialog offers a list of file formats to which you can save, but a) this includes only writable formats (not readable as well) and b) it is not available outside of QGIS as a comprehensive list.

Comment: I think you should submit a documentation enhancement request to the QGIS developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS has some own data providers but you can check the capabilities of the OGR formats with ogrinfo.

```
ogrinfo --formats
Supported Formats:
  BAG -raster,multidimensional raster,vector- (rw+v): Bathymetry Attributed Grid
  JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rov): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.5)
  FITS -raster,vector- (rw+): Flexible Image Transport System
  netCDF -raster,vector- (rw+s): Network Common Data Format
  PDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Geospatial PDF
  AmigoCloud -vector- (rw+): AmigoCloud
  PCIDSK -raster,vector- (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
  PDS4 -raster,vector- (rw+vs): NASA Planetary Data System 4
  VICAR -raster,vector- (rw+v): MIPL VICAR file
  JP2OpenJPEG -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
  MBTiles -raster,vector- (rw+v): MBTiles
  EEDA -vector- (ro): Earth Engine Data API
  OGCAPI -raster,vector- (rov): OGCAPI
  DB2ODBC -raster,vector- (rw+): IBM DB2 Spatial Database
  ESRI Shapefile -vector- (rw+v): ESRI Shapefile
  MapInfo File -vector- (rw+v): MapInfo File
  UK .NTF -vector- (rov): UK .NTF
  LVBAG -vector- (rov): Kadaster LV BAG Extract 2.0
  OGR_SDTS -vector- (rov): SDTS
  S57 -vector- (rw+v): IHO S-57 (ENC)
  DGN -vector- (rw+v): Microstation DGN
  OGR_VRT -vector- (rov): VRT - Virtual Datasource
  REC -vector- (ro): EPIInfo .REC
  Memory -vector- (rw+): Memory
  BNA -vector- (rw+v): Atlas BNA
  CSV -vector- (rw+v): Comma Separated Value (.csv)
  NAS -vector- (rov): NAS - ALKIS
  GML -vector- (rw+v): Geography Markup Language (GML)
  GPX -vector- (rw+v): GPX
  LIBKML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (LIBKML)
  KML -vector- (rw+v): Keyhole Markup Language (KML)
  GeoJSON -vector- (rw+v): GeoJSON
  GeoJSONSeq -vector- (rw+v): GeoJSON Sequence
  ESRIJSON -vector- (rov): ESRIJSON
  TopoJSON -vector- (rov): TopoJSON
  Interlis 1 -vector- (rw+v): Interlis 1
  Interlis 2 -vector- (rw+v): Interlis 2
  OGR_GMT -vector- (rw+v): GMT ASCII Vectors (.gmt)
  GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
  SQLite -vector- (rw+v): SQLite / Spatialite
  ODBC -vector- (rw+): ODBC
  WAsP -vector- (rw+v): WAsP .map format
  PGeo -vector- (ro): ESRI Personal GeoDatabase
  MSSQLSpatial -vector- (rw+): Microsoft SQL Server Spatial Database
  OGR_OGDI -vector- (ro): OGDI Vectors (VPF, VMAP, DCW)
  PostgreSQL -vector- (rw+): PostgreSQL/PostGIS
  MySQL -vector- (rw+): MySQL
  OpenFileGDB -vector- (rov): ESRI FileGDB
  XPlane -vector- (rov): X-Plane/Flightgear aeronautical data
  DXF -vector- (rw+v): AutoCAD DXF
  CAD -raster,vector- (rovs): AutoCAD Driver
  FlatGeobuf -vector- (rw+v): FlatGeobuf
  Geoconcept -vector- (rw+v): Geoconcept
  GeoRSS -vector- (rw+v): GeoRSS
  GPSTrackMaker -vector- (rw+v): GPSTrackMaker
  VFK -vector- (ro): Czech Cadastral Exchange Data Format
  PGDUMP -vector- (w+v): PostgreSQL SQL dump
  OSM -vector- (rov): OpenStreetMap XML and PBF
  GPSBabel -vector- (rw+): GPSBabel
  SUA -vector- (rov): Tim Newport-Peace's Special Use Airspace Format
  OpenAir -vector- (rov): OpenAir
  OGR_PDS -vector- (rov): Planetary Data Systems TABLE
  WFS -vector- (rov): OGC WFS (Web Feature Service)
  OAPIF -vector- (ro): OGC API - Features
  HTF -vector- (rov): Hydrographic Transfer Vector
  AeronavFAA -vector- (rov): Aeronav FAA
  Geomedia -vector- (ro): Geomedia .mdb
  EDIGEO -vector- (rov): French EDIGEO exchange format
  SVG -vector- (rov): Scalable Vector Graphics
  CouchDB -vector- (rw+): CouchDB / GeoCouch
  Cloudant -vector- (rw+): Cloudant / CouchDB
  Idrisi -vector- (rov): Idrisi Vector (.vct)
  ARCGEN -vector- (rov): Arc/Info Generate
  SEGUKOOA -vector- (rov): SEG-P1 / UKOOA P1/90
  SEGY -vector- (rov): SEG-Y
  ODS -vector- (rw+v): Open Document/ LibreOffice / OpenOffice Spreadsheet
  XLSX -vector- (rw+v): MS Office Open XML spreadsheet
  Elasticsearch -vector- (rw+): Elastic Search
  Walk -vector- (ro): Walk
  Carto -vector- (rw+): Carto
  SXF -vector- (rov): Storage and eXchange Format
  Selafin -vector- (rw+v): Selafin
  JML -vector- (rw+v): OpenJUMP JML
  PLSCENES -raster,vector- (ro): Planet Labs Scenes API
  CSW -vector- (ro): OGC CSW (Catalog  Service for the Web)
  VDV -vector- (rw+v): VDV-451/VDV-452/INTREST Data Format
  GMLAS -vector- (rwv): Geography Markup Language (GML) driven by application schemas
  MVT -vector- (rw+v): Mapbox Vector Tiles
  NGW -raster,vector- (rw+s): NextGIS Web
  MapML -vector- (rw+v): MapML
  TIGER -vector- (rw+v): U.S. Census TIGER/Line
  AVCBin -vector- (rov): Arc/Info Binary Coverage
  AVCE00 -vector- (rov): Arc/Info E00 (ASCII) Coverage
  HTTP -raster,vector- (ro): HTTP Fetching Wrapper
```

Comment: A little complement from https://gdal.org/programs/vector_common_options.html : " The format support is indicated as follows: ro is read-only driver; rw is read or write (i.e. supports CreateCopy()); rw+ is read, write and update (i.e. supports Create). A v is appended for formats supporting virtual IO (/vsimem, /vsigzip, /vsizip, etc). A s is appended for formats supporting subdatasets"